# hardcoding magento option to view

Tags: magento-1.7, products

I am working on a magento website that i did not create.
on the product page there are hardcoded custom options:

```
<textarea name="notes"></textarea>
```

i am trying to look for why the name is 'notes' i cannot find that in the option.
i would like to add another option however i do not know how to save it.
so if i find out why the name of the textarea is notes and it works to save i `would probably figure out how to add new hard coded options`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding more hard coded options seems like a bad idea. A better solution would be to create a module which isolates the functionality which they are looking for and allows management from the back end.

To find out how they are saving however, you will need to look at the form structure and controller.

Ie. Is it using Javascript to send this to the server and handling it some how differently based on whats in there.

I would imagine based on a name like that, they would be using something along the lines of: 
`$notes = $this->getRequest()->getParam('notes');`

So it is probably worth searching using a IDE for this or variants of it. But I suggest find the controller its going to first. From there you should be able to find it a lot easier.

Comment: the form is sending it like this form_key:miIi75HVE2m8aaqb
product:410
related_product:
options[18152]:4981
options[1960][]:1134
options[6997]:this is a test
options[6998]:
options[6999]:this is another test
options[7000]:כסף
options[7001]:
options[7002]:
options[7003]:
options[7004]:
options[7005]:
options[7006]:
isAtbah:yes
text:this is a test
notes:this is another test
qty:1
isAjax:1 how can i find the controller?

Comment: Look at where its sending the request to in Network Inspector, it should map to a Magento controller.

Comment: its sending it to http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5td2F4Yi5jby5pbC_XnteW15vXqNeV16ot15zXkNeZ16jXldei15nXnS3Xldep157Xl9eV16ov16nXkdeiLdeR16jXm9eV16ov15DXldeh16Mt16rXpNeZ15zXldeqLdee15PXldeo15It157Xkteg15g,/product/410/form_key/4SCpTrDkwwh2fmYP/

Answer (score 1):

Use a grep to search for the string "notes", since it is not the most common name it should point you to the right controller if the input is being used for anything.  Run this from your root Magento folder

```
find . | xargs grep 'notes' -sl
```